# Clojure: applyng function on every value in a map in vector of maps

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure

How to apply a function on every value in a map in vector of maps.

If I have a vector of maps

```
(def vector-of-maps [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])
```

And want to apply a function on every value in every map and as a result I want the same vector of  maps, something like this

```
(map #(+ 1 %) vector-of-maps)
```

So that the result is

```
[{:a 2 :b 3} {:a 4 :b 5}]
```

And I want it  to work with any vector of maps, not just this particular one....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=> (defn update-map [m f] (reduce-kv (fn [m k v] (assoc m k (f v))) {} m))
=> (map #(update-map % inc) vector-of-maps)
({:b 3, :a 2} {:b 5, :a 4})
```

Comment: can use `reduce-kv` here

Comment: @user100464 the order of keys is in reverse, is there a way to change that?

Comment: @user100464 and is there a way to just show the vals of the maps.

Comment: @Vesna your input map was unordered, and the output map is too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
(defn mapv-map-values [f vm]
  (letfn [(map-values [m] (zipmap (keys m) (map f (vals m))))]
    (mapv map-values vm)))
```

...  producing

```
(mapv-map-values inc [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])
;[{:b 3, :a 2} {:b 5, :a 4}]
```

The `map-values` function, the only significant departure from [@user100464's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064152/1562315), was adapted from [here](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-21_applying-functions-to.asciidoc).

Answer (score 1):

also you can do like this,but it is ugly

```
(defn dodo [m] (map (fn [map] (apply merge (for [[k v] map] (assoc {} k (inc v))))) m))

(dodo [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}])
;({:a 2, :b 3} {:a 4, :b 5})
```